# Getting async data in a react material table component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, material-table, use-state

I'm building a small react app using firebase for both hosting and storing data, I am using a Material-Table for showing the data. The problem is i get this error when I'm trying to load the data into the table:

> ```
> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to 
>     render a collection of children, use an array instead.
>     in EditTable (at App.js:12)
>     in div (at App.js:10)
>     in App (at src/index.js:10)
>     in StrictMode (at src/index.js:9)
> ```

This is the code for the table:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';
import { forwardRef } from 'react';

import AddBox from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import ArrowDownward from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Check from '@material-ui/icons/Check';
import ChevronLeft from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import ChevronRight from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight';
import Clear from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';
import DeleteOutline from '@material-ui/icons/DeleteOutline';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import FilterList from '@material-ui/icons/FilterList';
import FirstPage from '@material-ui/icons/FirstPage';
import LastPage from '@material-ui/icons/LastPage';
import Remove from '@material-ui/icons/Remove';
import SaveAlt from '@material-ui/icons/SaveAlt';
import Search from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ViewColumn from '@material-ui/icons/ViewColumn';
import {getShotjes} from './shotjesDao'

const tableIcons = {
    Add: forwardRef((props, ref) => <AddBox {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Check: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Check {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Clear: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Delete: forwardRef((props, ref) => <DeleteOutline {...props} ref={ref} />),
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Edit: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Edit {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Export: forwardRef((props, ref) => <SaveAlt {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Filter: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FilterList {...props} ref={ref} />),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ResetSearch: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Clear {...props} ref={ref} />),
    Search: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Search {...props} ref={ref} />),
    SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowDownward {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ThirdStateCheck: forwardRef((props, ref) => <Remove {...props} ref={ref} />),
    ViewColumn: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ViewColumn {...props} ref={ref} />)
};

export default async function EditTable() {

    const [state, setState] = React.useState({
        columns: [
            { title: 'ID', field: 'ID' , type: 'numeric' },
            { title: 'uitdeler', field: 'Uitdeler' },
            { title: 'ontvanger', field: 'Ontvanger' },
            { title: 'Uitgedeeld', field: 'Uitgedeeld', lookup: { 1: true, 0: false },},
            { title: 'datum', field: 'Datum',
            },
        ],
        data: getShotjes(),
    });


    return (
        <MaterialTable
            title="Editable Example"
            columns={state.columns}
            data={this.state.data}
            icons={tableIcons}
        />
    );
```

And here is my simple dao file minus the the config:

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

export async function getShotjes() {
        try {
            require("firebase/firestore");

            const firebaseConfig = {
            };

            if (!firebase.apps.length) {
                firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
            }

            var db = firebase.firestore();
            const snapshot = await db.collection('shotjes').get();
            return snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);

        }

}
```

EDIT:

So adding a useEffect hook and splitting the data and the columns states worked to remove all the errors. though i still don't see any data appear in the table. My Table component now looks like this:

```
export default function EditTable() {

var [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
        { title: 'ID', field: 'id' , type: 'numeric' },
        { title: 'Uitdeler', field: 'uitdeler' },
        { title: 'Ontvanger', field: 'ontvanger' },
        { title: 'Uitgedeeld', field: 'uitgedeeld', lookup: { 1: true, 0: false },},
        { title: 'Datum', field: 'datum',
        },
    ],
});

var [data, setData] = React.useState([]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const result = await getShotjes();
        console.log(result);
        setData(result);
    })();
}, []);


return (
    <MaterialTable
        title="Editable Example"
        columns={state.columns}
        data={data.data}
        icons={tableIcons}
    />
);
}
```

Comment: Call `getShotjes()` in a `useEffect` hook, and instead of returning the data, use `setData(data)` to set it (separate columns and data in your state).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Answer (score 1):

This is how i fixed it, I also added functionality for adding an removing data.

EditTable.js:

```
export default function EditTable() {

var [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
        { title: 'ID', field: 'id', type: 'numeric', editable: false},
        { title: 'Uitdeler', field: 'uitdeler' },
        { title: 'Ontvanger', field: 'ontvanger' },
        { title: 'Datum', field: 'datum', type: 'date'},
    ],
});

var [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    // By moving this function inside the effect, we can clearly see the values it uses.
    setIsLoading(true);
    async function fetchProduct() {
        if (!firebase.apps.length) {
            firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        }

        setData(await getShotjes());
        setIsLoading(false);

    }

    fetchProduct();
}, []);

const handleCreateShotje = async (shotje)  => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await addShotje(shotje).then(async () => {
        setData(await getShotjes());
    });
    setIsLoading(false);
};
const handleDeleteShotje = async (id)  => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await removeShotje(id).then(async () => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setTimeout(async function () {{
            setData(await getShotjes());
            }
        }, 400);
        setIsLoading(false);
    });

};

return (
    <MaterialTable

        title="Shotjes"
        columns={state.columns}
        data={(data)}
        icons={tableIcons}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        editable={{
            isEditable: rowData => rowData.name === "id", // make id not editable
            onRowAdd: (newData) => handleCreateShotje(newData),
            onRowDelete: (oldData) => handleDeleteShotje(oldData.id)

        }}
    />

);
}
```